# Shared functions.php across multiple WordPress websites

Tags: functions, multi-author

I find myself using many of the same snippets of code for my `functions.php` file in new websites.

Is there a method I can use to create a few different shared `functions.php` files to use across my websites? I am not referring to a WPMU installation, but completely separate installations of WordPress with separate databases, possibly on different hosts.

For example, if there are functions I want to add to a specific site, I would just add them to the site's own `functions.php`, but also have a shared `functions.php` file for all my multi-author sites and one for all my single author sites. Another situation would be to group together all similar functions into separate `functions.php` files.

## UPDATE

Here is an update with an example I found in a premium theme's `functions.php`. This is the only code in the `functions.php`, so I assume all the functions are pulled from other files.

```
$themename = 'CoolTheme';
$shortname = 'cooltheme';

include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/plugins/pagination.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/plugins/cool_widgets.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/plugins/sidebar_generator.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/cool_comments.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/cool_functions.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/cool_navigation.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/cool_panel/cool_panel.php';
include_once TEMPLATEPATH.'/cool_framework/cool_shortcodes/cool_shortcodes.php';
```

Is something like this possible, except calling the functions from a completely separate domain or cloud storage? If so, what are the issues, if any, I can expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your functions can go in a single file (no images, or linked js/css files), you could add them to mu-plugin file. See the [Must Use Plugins page on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) for more information.

EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CommonCodes
Plugin URI: http://you.com/
Description: A common use file
Version: 1.0
Author: You
Author URI: http://you.com/
*/

function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
}
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );
}

function all_settings_link() {
    add_options_page(__('All Settings'), __('All Settings'), 'administrator', 'options.php');
}
    add_action('admin_menu', 'all_settings_link');

?>
```

You would then just save it as `commonfunctions.php` or whatever. Create a folder in the `wp-content` directory called `mu-plugins` and place the single PHP file in that folder. It will auto-activate, and can't be removed from the WP-Admin area.

Any issues you might face would depend on the plug-ins or themes that could possibly re-use the same functions causing a conflict.

Comment: As mentioned, this is NOT for a MU site. I am not referring to a WPMU installation, but completely separate installations of WordPress with separate databases, possibly on different hosts.

Comment: @TravisPflanz The directory `mu-plugins` is for _must use_ plugins, not for multi-site. These plugins are not very different from regular plugins, they just run without an explicit activation.

Comment: Oh. Never heard of that before. Would you mind editing the answer with some solid references?

Comment: @toscho Thanks for updating the answer. I've never actually seen the codex page. I never knew the mu-plugins loaded before normal plugins, or that activation hooks are not executed.

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at [this article](http://www.gilluminate.com/2011/12/23/host-your-own-custom-wordpress-plugin-updater/) about how to update a self-hosted plugin. This would allow you to setup your functions.php as a functionality plugin and then host it in one place and push updates to all sites. You'd still have to go to each site and update it, but I imagine this would still be an improvement over your current setup.

You also might consider creating a set of options for the plugin that turns on and off sets of functions. Then you could just have a single plugin with all your functions that you then turn on and off per-site.

=====

EDIT: It turns out that there's even a plugin to help deal with self-hosting plugins. It's called...wait for it... [Self Hosted Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/self-hosted-plugins/). I haven't used it, so I can't vouch for it, but it could be worth checking out if the above tutorial doesn't pan out.

Comment: I added an update to the question. I prefer not to write a complete plugin, as I am not a coder.

Comment: Plugins aren't all that complicated. A functions.php file is practically a plugin, it's just missing the standard plugin header information (http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers). Also, I suspect that any securely-configured server would block you from loading a file from an external server in the way you mentioned. Hence, I'd still consider looking in to this answer.